# How to fade out textarea after copying the value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, textarea, fadeout

I have this basic HTML code:

```
<textarea id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10">This is sample value</textarea>
```

How can I fade out the textarea after 1 second after user press `Ctr + C` after selecting or right click and copy the text `This is sample value` in the textarea?

Comment: You can catch Ctrl+C with the usual `keydown` event handler, but there's no way to tell whether the text was copied when right-clicking as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery `copy` event along with `setTimeout` function:

```
$('#textarea').on('copy', function() {    
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#textarea').fadeOut();
    }, 1000);
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XRTV8/)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you'll also want to cancel the fadeOut if the user has a change of heart:

```
$('#textarea').on('copy focus', function(e) {
    switch (e.type){
        case 'copy':
            $(this).blur().delay(1000).fadeOut();
            break;
        case 'focus':
            $(this).stop(true, false).css({ 'opacity': '1' });
            break;
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/atombob/k3U75/)